# Android repeating alarm works after click button

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, setting, repeatingalarm

I'm creating an alarm which works every ten minutes. When i click a button for setting an alarm, alarm works in a second and it works every ten minute. Why alarm works in first minute and it works every ten minutes?

```
AlarmManager alarm_kur = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarm_gorev = new Intent(ilac_hatirlatma.this, hatirlatma_detay.class);
alarm_gorev.putExtra("alarm", "alarm" + yeni_alarm_sayisi);
alarm_kur.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*60*1000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ilac_hatirlatma.this, 1, alarm_gorev, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just Change setRepeating() to set()

```
//Argument
set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)
```

Comment: Sorry, it gave me an error like Error:(114, 26) error: method set in class AlarmManager cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,long,PendingIntent
found: int,long,int,PendingIntent
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Ok,Check complete example of ==

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarm_id, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, set your time, pendingIntent);

Comment: Still same, when i click the button it works immediately.

Comment: You can use Calendar

       Calendar  calendar= Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
           calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
           calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
           calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

           calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
           calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mint);
           calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

and set calendar time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

Comment: Cool, but how can i implement that solution in to my code.

Comment: Complete your code here...

Intent alarm_gorev = new Intent(ilac_hatirlatma.this, hatirlatma_detay.class);
     alarm_gorev.putExtra("alarm", "alarm" + yeni_alarm_sayisi);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarm_id, alarm_gorev,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+10*60*1000, pendingIntent);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106215/discussion-between-rathod-vijay-and-user2265473).